# Ação apos o fim do foreach

Tags: php, foreach

Bom, eu tenho um `foreach` e gostaria de executar algum script logo após ele chegar ao fim. Mas como faço essa verificação?

```
foreach ($array as $id_video) {
   $resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, "INSERT INTO exercicios (id_treino_exercicio, id_aluno_exercicio, dia_exercicio) VALUES ('$id_video', '$id_aluno_exercicio', '$dia_exercicio')");
}
```

Comment: Bastaria colocar algum código após o bloco do `foreach`, não? Se ele "passou" do `foreach`, não precisa verificar, pois sabe-se que ele já "acabou"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para executar uma ação após o `foreach`, basta colocar o código no final.

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
      // Código dentro do loop
}

// Código depois do foreach
echo "Foreach finalizado com sucesso";
```

O código fornecido dentro de `foreach` é executado e, apenas após o fim do loop, é que o código subsequente é utilizado.

Comment: vou testar aqui